# Change DNS when on Wi-Fi, ideally without reflection?

Tags: android, dns, wifimanager

Before Android 4.0 we were able to change DNS settings. How can we do it after Android 4.0?

The app will be used legally by our users. The app will check when a user is on Wifi and if they are using our predefined DNS. If not, the app will set it.

Is reflection the only way to do it after Android 4.0?

Comment: Hopefully, this is not possible, except perhaps via device administration APIs. That would be a major security flaw otherwise, if arbitrary apps can hijack the DNS resolution process.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I was afraid of the security issues even thou the app is completely legal. What other method do you suggest? Opening settings for user to change the DNS? Also, do you agree that reflection is a bad way to go with the commercial app?

Comment: "What other method do you suggest? Opening settings for user to change the DNS?" -- I guess. I have no idea why any app would need to be messing with the DNS settings, outside of apps for dedicated DNS services (e.g., OpenDNS) or *maybe* a VPN client. "Also, do you agree that reflection is a bad way to go with the commercial app?" -- well, hopefully that doesn't work either, at least for newer Android versions. Just because there's a fig leaf of reflection doesn't mean that this is any less of a security issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare The product is bound to the DNS settings. If the proper DNS is not set, it will not work as intended. On 3G/4G mode, this can be done on the ISP side. But on Wi-Fi we have to make sure the DNS is set. One option is to do it automatically and not bother a user, other way is to constantly remind a user to set DNS (users hate this). So it's kind of a sword with two blades. Any suggestion?

Comment: The normal way to do this is to have your WiFi set the DNS server when it gives an address, it's one of the DHCP options and it is probably already setting it to something if the WiFi works properly. Change it to assign your internal DNS server instead of whatever it assigns now.

Comment: "Any suggestion?" -- fix the product to not be bound to the DNS settings.

Comment: Oh hang on, "the product is bound to the DNS" meaning you want to hijack random customer's devices and set their DNS to your company's servers, breaking their internal name resolution and spying on their web use? Don't do that.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler No, nothing like that. It's a card they put in their device and they purchase the card.

Comment: @CommonsWare This works in 99% of cases, but not in this one I am afraid. So the only way is not to have it and have users set it themselves, and keep complaining that the card is not working (as they skipped setting DNS when on Wifi)

Comment: There's a difference between *warning* the person that "hey, you need to fix your DNS settings" and *changing those settings*. If you can determine programmatically that the settings are wrong (and I'm assuming that you can, somehow), warning the user, with a one-tap option to get them as close to the right spot in Settings as you can, is perfectly reasonable. But apps should not be able to change the DNS resolution process -- while *you* may not be doing malicious things with that capability, others could.

Comment: @CommonsWare I get you. That's the reason they do not allow this. But you made me thinking saying "if you can check what DNS settings user use". I thought it was possible by default (`WifiManager` or similar classes and its getters). I will double check on this as well.

Comment: I don't know what the OP's use case was, but one example would be in a location where the powers controlling network infrastructure are hostile, and are censoring certain web sites, and blocking VPNs. An app that could frequently change DNS settings could help a user evade such blockages, but few users will persevere in frequently change DNS settings manually.

Comment: Sure, changing DNS settings is a dangerous power, but so is the power to send messages over the internet (Google used to classify Internet permission as dangerous). Android has a system for managing dangerous permissions, so that they can be granted to certain apps and not others.